# Import Material design to Angular 2 + webpack

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2 and have a problem
I use Angular2 + webpack, I'm importing Angular Material components but it doesn't work

```js
//////////////////
// WEBPACK
///////////
new DllBundlesPlugin({
   bundles: {
     '@angular/material',
     }
  })

// APP MODULE
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
// Should I use @angular/material or @angular2-material
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular2-material';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
imports: [MetarialModule.forRoot()]
})

// COMPONENT
// import { MdButton } from '@angular/material';
import { MdButton } from '@angular2-material/button';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.html',
  directive: [MdButton] // It says
  //Generic type 'Type<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)
  // Argument of type '{ selector: string; template: any; directives: typeof MdButton[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  //Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'. 
})
```

Am I using wrong version or haven't include something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@angular2-material` is quite old and deprecated.

You should use `@angular/material`.

I'm not sure MetarialModule.forRoot() is needed in the latest release.
I think that anyway you can leave it but it'll be deprecated soon.

As you've imported MaterialModule in your module, you don't need to import every material component one by one. You'll have access to them directly.

If you want to use material in an other module than the one you imported MetarialModule.forRoot(), remember to import (**only**) MaterialModule.

---

**Friendly advice [off topic]:**

> I'm new to Angular 2 and have a problem I use Angular2 + webpack

If you don't want to have to handle that kind of things on your own and focus on Angular, you should rather use [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

If you want to give a try with latest version :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new your-awesome-project
cd your-awesome-project
ng serve
```

You're now setup .

To build : `ng build --prod`

Take a look in the Github repo to be aware of the commands that you can use `ng generate ...` etc.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your advice. I've tryed to understand how it works.
Angular - Cli works fine, but can't understand where Webpack configs

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've understood Webpack doesn't included, I need to do some manipulations

Comment: angular-cli is making some work on op of webpack and you don't have access to webpack config. There's an issue about that you can take a look here : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656#issuecomment-240171375 and https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656#issuecomment-239366723 ... If you need to access webpack config you should definitly not use angular-cli then ...